# How do I move elements (i.e. divs, head, body) around in CSS and change the background color properly?

Tags: html, css, flask

Hello so I'm having trouble with css, I'm trying to move it around and change the background color however I cannot seem to do so but I'm able to change other properties of it like center it and weight

python file:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/homepage')
def homepage():
return render_template('homepage.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run(debug=True)
```

html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url_for('static',filename='homepage.css')}}">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
    <div class="navbar">
      <h1 id=home>Home <h2>
      <h1 id=about>About <h2>
      <h1 id=location>Location <h2>
    </div>
  <h1 id=logo>4/12</h1>
</head>

<body>
  <h1> welcome to the homepage</h1>
</body>
```

css page:

```
  background-color: #333333;
}
#logo{
  position: relative;
}
#home{
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
#about{
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
#location{
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Well the first thing that jumps out is that you can't have page content in the `<head>` of an HTML page. Your navbar must be in the `<body>`. However, aside from that, your question is much too vague, and centering of *any* kind has really been covered quite deeply elsewhere on Stack Overflow. Consider doing a bit of searching for your exact issue.

Comment: Does `background-color: green;` in your css not work?

Comment: As per previous comment, I've moved the navbar to body and I've tried adding background-color: green; but nothing is applied

Answer (score 0):

Place your Nav in the body all HTML code shown on screen goes in the body.

Next place a body tag on your background color in CSS.

```css
body{

  background-color: #333333;
}
#logo{
  position: relative;
}
#home{
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
#about{
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
#location{
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url_for('static',filename='homepage.css')}}">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
     <h1> welcome to the homepage</h1>
      <div class="navbar">
      <h1 id=home>Home <h2>
      <h1 id=about>About <h2>
      <h1 id=location>Location <h2>
    </div>
  <h1 id=logo>4/12</h1>
</body>
```